# How to join two tables on upload data using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i have two tables with existing data where i'm trying to associate them with sequelize on upload,

where table one ( get_awgs)has:

```
id| awg | area |
```

and table two (harnes_detial)has which would be uploaded:

```
id| gauge | description | price
```

where I have associated them by:

```
 Harness.belongsTo(Awg,{constraints: false, foregineKey:'getAwgId'});
 Awg.hasMany(Harness);
```

I have and updated query by a foreignKey

```
PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (getAwgId) REFERENCES get_awgs (id) 
    ON DELETE SET NULL 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and when I route my model

```
router.get("/mergeTable/:awg", (req, res)=>{
  var awg = req.params.awg;
  Harness.findAll({where: {gauge: awg}, include:[{model: Awg}]}).then(resutls =>{
  res.send(JSON.stringify(resutls));
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

its says : SQL message: "Unknown column 'harnes_detial.getAwgId' in 'field list'",
when i `.sync({force: true})` i get the field name but by this is will have an empty table and i cannot join two tables for result as if i upload data i will not have the created field by sequelize. it works if i do it manually...what would be the automation process.

i wanted to have

table two (harnes_detial)has:

```
id| gauge | description | price | getAwgId
1    20       xyz          30      1
2    30       xyz          20      2
3    40       xyz          50      3
4    20       xyz          60      1
```

how do i get this awgId updated with existing data on uploading table two data ? please help ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined sequelize associations properly. You are trying to associate tables `awg` and `harnes_detial` but the query generated by ORM says that it is associating `harnes_detial` with `get_awgs`.

Another observation is you expect ORM to generate `getAwgId` column in `harness_detial` table automatically but ORM expects you to have a database column beforehand. You can map the foreign keys and target keys.

I recommend you to follow [official documentation of sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html) and [this](https://medium.com/@eth3rnit3/sequelize-relationships-ultimate-guide-f26801a75554) blog to understand more about how to define sequelize associations.

Hope it helps!